# QtDataStream::writeRawData reorders my bytes

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to save a raw byte array into a file:

```
mDataStream.writeRawData( ( (const char *)&testPacket), 188);
```

The test packet is just an array of unsigned char, the packet is copied in the right size, but the bytes are reordered. ie: 0x47 0x00 0x10 0x20 ... becomes 0x00 0x47 ox20 0x10.

This looks like an endianness problem, but i've tried setting the byte order to little endian with unsuccessful results.

Comment: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdatastream.html#writeRawData what returns mDataStream.byteOrder()?

Comment: I've tried mDataStream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian); but it doesnt change anything